# SQL query - comparing values to show availability

Tags: php, mysql, sql, primary-key

Just getting to grips with some more advance sql queries and a bit stuck with one of them. I’ve been working on a small cinema project that allows user to book seats for upcoming productions.

In a table for chairs, I’ve created a query so that checkboxes are created on all of the chairs within a particular cinema area. However, I now need to add some sort of functionality to show chair availability i.e. whether one has already been booked by a previous order.

Comment: Give the `Area` the table prefix it is for; or include the full error message, that was a guess.

Comment: could you post the actual table schemas and also that of the bookings table you mention?

Comment: `Booki1` doesn't have `Area`?

Comment: updated schema for the database

Comment: yes - no Area in Booki1.

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: No bookings table nor the area table??

Comment: no error messages now - but it prints out multiple SeatNo (more than what is in the actual zone i.e. stalls hold 30 seats so should be 30 checkboxes - it now prints out around 180) .. not sure whats happening but definitely to do with the query.

Comment: area table added - booki1 is the Bookings table ( should have pointed that out - apologises)

Comment: You are not joining the tables - more like compounding data from each. You need to join each table with the relevant keys

Comment: can you show me from the schema provided? really lost but eager to learn!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from `chairs` c
left outer join `booki1` b on b.`seatno`=c.`seatno`
left outer join `shows` s on s.`ddate`=b.`ddate`
left outer join `area` a on a.`name`=c.`area`
where (
    c.`area` like '{$_SESSION['Area']}' and 
    s.`ddate` like '{$_SESSION['DDate']}' and 
    s.`ttime` like '{$_SESSION['TTime']}}'
    );
```

Very hastily put together and totally untested, but you need to join the tables using suitable keys.